# How to make custom discrete color data function

Tags: plotting, graphics, color, visualization

Attempting to make custom discrete color data function:

my custom color:

[image]

is it possible to use my custom color

```
colors = Reverse@Table[Hue@h, {h, 0, 0.7, 1/10}] // N;
```

Thanks to [mfvonh](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5059/mfvonh), color function and color data

```
cf[x_] := 
 Which @@ Flatten[
  MapThread[
  List, {x >= # & /@ Reverse@Most@Range[0, 1, 1/Length@colors],  colors}]]

 colordata=cf /@ Rescale[pts[[All, 2]], {0,0.1}];
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can just make your own function, though in most situations you can just pass a list of colors.

```
colors = Table[Hue@h, {h, 0, 0.7, 1/10}];
discrete[x_] := Part[colors, x];
ContourPlot[x + Sin[x^2 + y^2], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, Contours -> 9,
  ContourShading -> colors]
```

[image]

For a gradient, use `Blend`:

```
gradient[x_] := Blend[colors, x];
Plot3D[Exp[-x^2 - y^2], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
 ColorFunction -> (gradient[#3] &)]
```

[image]

Comment: Can you give an example? In `Graphics` you usually specify colors explicitly with directives.

Comment: Here's the basic idea in most `Graphics` situations: `Riffle[Table[Rectangle[{i, 0}], {i, 8}], colors]`. (Add `//Graphics` to see it rendered.)

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean, but perhaps this? `Graphics3D[{PointSize@.02, First@colors, Riffle[pts, colors]} /. p : {__?NumericQ} -> Point[p]]`.

Comment: That's related to the plotting function. Look at the "Details"  section in the [ColorFunction docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ColorFunction.html)

Comment: `Graphics[GraphicsComplex[pts,{Polygon@poly},VertexColors->(gradient/@Rescale[pts[[All,2]],{0,0.1}])],AspectRatio->1/2,Frame->True]`

Comment: That's because a discrete color set and a continuous (gradient) color set work differently. In a discrete color set, generally the color does not convey information -- it's just a way to visually distinguish two pieces of data. By contrast, gradients are usually used to convey information through color, such as in the `Plot3D` above -- the color corresponds to the height. If you look at the definition of `discrete`, it's just giving you the nth element of the list of `colors`. Try `VertexColors->colors`.

Comment: The documentation on this is not the best. It would be worth your time to read the full entry on `ColorData` and work through the examples. It's extremely useful and once you wrap your mind around it you'll find it quite easy.

Comment: Do you have the code to generate that image?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15217/discussion-between-mfvonh-and-being-human).